# R coefplot error: Error in f(..., self = self)

Tags: r, coefplot

I am using coefplot() (from coefplot package) to plot the result of a logit model. The model is just straightforward without additional specification and has no missing values, so I don't want to get down to ggplot2 to produce a customized plot.
That said, when I throw my result (an object) to coefplot() function, it returns this error message:

```
Error in f(..., self = self) : attempt to apply non-function
```

I then checked with their R [document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coefplot/coefplot.pdf) and replicated their example code (p.4), I received the same error message again. Not sure what's going on, but I have made sure that I closed all prior plotting devices and did not name my data as "data."

Is there something I miss or some prior processing required?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has occurred to me.
I could settle it by raising the version of the software.

Check your R version.
My R version was 3.2.2.
Now R version is 3.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

[Note] What follows below is NOT an answer to my original question.

I still have no idea what's going on. Both my R-studio and R versions are up to date, I can't never get coefplot() to work on my R-studio but sometimes it works on R.